# Connection to BigQuery in Power BI

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi

I want to make a report with data from a dataset shared with me within BigQuery. The problem is when I connect to the database I can only see "My Project" and "Public Datasets".

[Power BI screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8aHZ.jpg)

[BigQuery screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlprs.jpg)

Is this because I we can't see datasets which are shared with us and which haven't been created by us?
Or is it a problem with the Power BI connector?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

Q: Is this because I we can't see datasets which are shared with us and which haven't been created by us?

A: You should be able to see datasets that are shared with you even if you haven't created it. If someone shared one with you, you probably got an email saying:

```
John Doe has shared the BigQuery dataset <PROJECT_NAME>:<DATASET_NAME> with you. To access this dataset, you can use the BigQuery browser tool or the BigQuery command line tool.

When using the BigQuery browser tool, you may need to add project <PROJECT_NAME> for display by following the instructions here.
```

From this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-classic-ui#adding_and_removing_projects) you can view the steps to perform to add the project from which the dataset has been shared to your own project.

Q: Is it a problem with the Power BI connector?

A: I would suggest you to reach out to the  [Power BI Support team](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/support/free/) to have them answer this question since I'm not familiar with this tool.